# I am trying to play live streaming API in MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, live-streaming

Hi I am trying to play live streaming api in my app but their is some error occurs like below...

> Response Fail. Error : The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa
>   error 3840.)

please help to sort out this problem

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    NSLog(@"%@",arrayId);



    Service *srv=[[Service alloc]init];

    NSString *str=@"http://streamtvbox.com/site/api/matrix/";
    NSString *method=@"channel";
    NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict setValue:arrayId forKey:@"id"];

    [srv postToURL:str withMethod:method andParams:dict completion:^(BOOL success, NSDictionary *responseObj)

     {
         if (success) {
             NSLog(@"Hello I am success");

         }
         NSLog(@"%@",responseObj);


         _player =  [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:responseObj];
         [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:_player];

     }];



}
```

Answer (score 0):

`AVPlayerItem` is the best choice in this case as you have more control.
See the below code snippet. I have given you just basic example. You do some re-search on `AVPlayerItem`.

**Define your AVPlayer object:**

```
AVPlayer *videoPlayer;
```

**Prepare AVPlayer and add Observers:**

```
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageText]];
videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:[videoPlayer currentItem]];
[videoPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(updateProgress:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

**Handling callbacks:**

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context 
 {
        if (object == videoPlayer && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"])
        {
            if (videoPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed)
            {
                NSLog(@"AVPlayer Failed");
            } 

            else if (videoPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay)
            {
                NSLog(@"AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay");
                [videoPlayer play];
            } 

            else if (videoPlayer.status == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown)
            {
                NSLog(@"AVPlayer Unknown");
            }
        }

        if (object == videoPlayer && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp"])
        {
            if (videoPlayer.playbackLikelyToKeepUp)
            {
                // Hide Activity indicator
                [videoPlayer play];
            }
        }

        if (object == videoPlayer && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"playbackBufferEmpty"])
        {
            if (videoPlayer.playbackBufferEmpty)
            {
                // Show Activity indicator
                [videoPlayer pause];
            }
        }
    }

- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {

     //  code here whatever you want to do on finishing video stream..
}
```